# how to close python process on program end

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial

I fail to close a serial connection that runs in a process properly at the end of the program. (on windows/VSCode and Ctrl-C)

I get an error message and most of the time the port is already opened at the next start of the program.

Do I have to finish the run process first?

```
class serialOne(Process):
    def __init__(self, serial_port, debug, baudrate=57600, timeout=1):
    ...

    def terminate(self):
        print("close ports")
        self.active = False
        self.ser.close()

    def run(self):
        while self.active:
            self.initCom()
            self.readCom()
            time.sleep(0.005)

    def main():
        global processList
        global debug

        while True:
            if debug == True:
                print("main")
            time.sleep(1.0)

        for process in processList:
            process.terminate()
```

and my main:

```
def main():
    global processList
    global debug

    while True:
        if debug == True:
            print("main") # actually doing nothing
        time.sleep(1.0)

    for process in processList:
        process.terminate()
```

that's the error message:

```
Process serialOne-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dgapp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\_python\rfid_jacky\simple_multiprocess_rfid_02.py", line 129, in run
    time.sleep(0.005)
  File "c:\Users\dgapp\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 45, in <module>
KeyboardInterrupt
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\Users\dgapp\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 265, in main
    wait=args.wait)
  File "c:\Users\dgapp\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 258, in handle_args
    debug_main(addr, name, kind, *extra, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\dgapp\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_local.py", line 45, in debug_main
    run_file(address, name, *extra, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\dgapp\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_local.py", line 79, in run_file
    run(argv, addr, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\dgapp\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_local.py", line 140, in _run
    _pydevd.main()
  File "c:\Users\dgapp\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1925, in main
    debugger.connect(host, port)
  File "c:\Users\dgapp\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1283, in run
    return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)
  File "c:\Users\dgapp\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1290, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "c:\Users\dgapp\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 25, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "e:\_python\rfid_jacky\simple_multiprocess_rfid_02.py", line 161, in <module>
    main()
  File "e:\_python\rfid_jacky\simple_multiprocess_rfid_02.py", line 140, in main
    time.sleep(1.0)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press `Ctrl+C`,  a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception is thrown, and interrupts your infinite sleep loop. But since you don't catch this exception, the code *after* this loop (with `process.terminate()`) is never called, which probably causes your issue.

So you have several options:

- catch `KeyboardInterrupt` and use that to exit the inifite loop:

  ```
  def main():
      global processList
      global debug

      try:
          while True:
              if debug == True:
                  print("main") # actually doing nothing
              time.sleep(1.0)
      except KeyboardInterrupt:
          pass

      for process in processList:
          process.terminate()
  ```

  Which is simple and very readable.
- register an exit handler that will be run when your program exits:

  ```
  import atexit

  @atexit.register
  def shutdown():
      global processList

      for process in processList:
          process.terminate()

  def main():
      global debug

      while True:
          if debug == True:
              print("main") # actually doing nothing
          time.sleep(1.0)
  ```

  Which is more reliable since it will work even if your process is terminated by another signal.

Answer (score 0):

The [KeyboardInterrupt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) happens when the user hits the interrupt key.

A simple solution would be to catch the exception:

```
while True:
    if debug == True:
        print("main") # actually doing nothing

    try:
        # do your things
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("program was interrupted by user")
        break
```

You could also use the `finally` keyword to properly end your program:

```
try:
    while True:
        # do your things    
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("program was interrupted by user")
    break
finally:
    close()  # this will always happen, even if an exception was raised
```